# VBA - Formula Array doe

Tags: excel, vba

I tried to use `.FormulaArray` to get the smallest value in a column, but unfortunatly it does not work.

This is my code for the formula:

```
Worksheets("Test Sim").Range("B9").FormulaArray = "{=MIN(IF(B2:B8>0;B2:B8;""""))}"
```

If i write it without the curly braces **runtime error 1004** appears, if i write it with them my table looks like this:

[image]

As you can see in B9 it will not show the number 9. what do i have to change that this will work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the {} and when entering formulas via code you need to use the "US-style" comma separator.

```
Worksheets("Test Sim").Range("B9").FormulaArray = "=MIN(IF(B2:B8>0,B2:B8,""""))"
```